# Github Rest API: find repositories by keyword for a specific user

Tags: rest, github-api

I want to find a repositories by keyword for a specific user using Github Rest Api.
My query: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=go&user=kotelliada 
But this query gives the wrong answer.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Running your code returns the response it seems you want.  Since your code is so incomplete, I don't know if you are having trouble receiving the info on the server-side or client-side.